# Why is the first div and its image not being rendered?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

the first div is just hidden even when i tell it to take h-full of the h-2/3 container +  the img has full cover but i cant manage to figure out why it doesnt render the image on these 2 cases.

First Case:

```
<div class="bg-gray-900 flex mx-auto px-12 py-12 h-2/3 w-full">
  <div class="relative w-1/2 h-full bg-white">
  <img
      class="absolute h- w-full object-cover"
      src="https://unsplash.com/photos/TseVAW2e2EM"
      alt=""
      />
      </div>

   <div class="bg-white text-white">dsadsadddaada</div>
</div>
```

Second Case:

```
<div class="flex justify-around flex-wrap">
          <div class="w-1/4 px-6 bg-white h-512px rounded-lg overflow-hidden border shadow-lg">
            <div class="relative pb-2/3">
              <img
                class="absolute h-full w-full object-cover"
                src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/the_roaming_platypus"
                alt="https://source.unsplash.com/user/the_roaming_platypus"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="p-6">
              <div class="mt-2 inline-block bg-teal-200 text-teal-800 text-xs px-2 rounded-full uppercase font-semibold tracking-wide">
                New
              </div>
              <h4 class="mt-1 font-semibold text-lg leading-tight truncate">
                Iphone 10
              </h4>
              <div class="mt-2 flex items-center">
                <span class="ml-2 text-gray-600 text-sm">34 reviews</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the link used in the first example is somewhat incorrect since it does cross-origin response with mime type html/text, while the link in the second example return an image.

If you place link 2 in the first case - the picture will render normally.

So your question has nothing to do with html or css.

Comment: both the images or divs render nothing on my side.

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle then?
Here is mine with second image as source [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms38ztub/)